# Rails method executing, when it should not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
rails 3.2
```

In my tickets_controller, I have the following:

```
def update
  @ticket = Ticket.find params[:id]
  authorize! :update, @ticket
  @ticket.assign_attributes(params[:ticket])
  @ticket.customer_info.company = @ticket.customer if @ticket.customer_info
  @ticket.admin_context = true
  if !params[:ticket_update_type].nil? && params[:ticket_update_type] == 'save_lead_billing'
    @ticket.process_lead_billing params
  end
  if @ticket.save
    @ticket.update_attribute(:ticket_type, @ticket.ticket_profile.ticket_type)
    redirect_to [:admin, @ticket], notice: success_message
  else
    @ticket.customer_info_type = 'existing'
    @can_update_ticket = can? :update, @ticket
    @tag_groups = TagGroup.with_type('ticket').for_company(@ticket.customer_id)
    flash.now[:error] = @ticket.errors.full_messages.join(', ')
    render action: "show"
  end
end
```

In my ticket.rb model, I have the following:

```
def process_lead_billing params
  if params[:lead_billing]["pre_tax_total"].nil? || params[:lead_billing]["post_tax_total"].nil?
    return
  end
  # handles case where billing infor has not been added to lead ticket
  if params[:ticket_update_type] == "save_lead_billing"
    lead_billing = LeadBilling.new(
        :ticket_id => self.id,
        :pre_tax_total => params[:lead_billing]["pre_tax_total"],
        :post_tax_total => params[:lead_billing]["post_tax_total"],
        :status => 'entered'
    )
    lead_billing.save!
  end
```

end

And in lead_billing.rb model, I have the following:

```
class LeadBilling < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :pre_tax_total, :post_tax_total
  validates_numericality_of :pre_tax_total, greater_than: 0, allow_blank: false, only_integer: false
  validates_numericality_of :post_tax_total, greater_than_or_equal_to: :pre_tax_total, allow_blank: false, only_integer: false
```

The problem, is that when the form is submitted, with the pre_tax_total and post_tax_total empty, I am getting an error message.

From the log file:

```
Started PUT "/admin/tickets/163812" for 73.83.66.151 at 2016-12-21 22:05:28 +0000
Processing by Admin::TicketsController#update as HTML
```

and the params are:

```
[utf8] => ✓
[authenticity_token] => mNt+aI3YInoutup4UsBGZ8zZkeFRYCBZAsxEv4JPvoE=
[ticket] => Array
    (
         ......
    )

[time_span] => 
[city] => Draper
[state] => Utah
[admin] => true
[specialty] => 
[services] => 
[inventories] => 
[ticket_update_type] => save_lead_billing
[ticket_id] => 1480720184_0388234_ticket
[lead_billing] => Array
    (
        [pre_tax_total] => 
        [post_tax_total] => 
    )

[id] => 163812
```

From the log file, the error is:

```
Validation failed: Pre tax total can't be blank, Pre tax total is not
a number, Post tax total can't be blank, Post tax total is not a number from
```

And then it points me to the line in the tickets_controller.rb, where the processing_lead_billing method is called (correctly), and then to the line in the processing_lead_billing method, where it tries to save the lead billing.

Execution should have halted, when I checked for nil, but it continued to execute. Any ideas?

Comment: could just be the debugger showing the wrong location in your file. try throwing in a `puts` or debugger in that method and see if it's actually invoked.

Comment: It's not clear from your params you copied if the content is nil or just blank (i.e. ""), in which case your method would not return (you should test blank? instead of nil?)

Comment: @Nycen: It turns out it was sending a blank, and not a null. And I did some testing, and it turns out that if I do a test for object.blank? it covers for both a blank and a null, so I used that instead and it's working fine. If you turn this into an answer, I will credit you for it.

Comment: Thanks @EastsideDeveloper and glad that solved it. I added an answer with a bit more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails has a blank? method that is usually preferred when testing form params.

nil? is a ruby method that will only return true if the object is nil, while blank? covers all sorts of use cases (empty string, empty array, empty dictionary and of course nil value).

In your case, the returned value are most likely empty string given how rails work, and so you should test for blank? instead of nil?.